# How do i auto hide a div when selecting a second div in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm having a hard time trying to figure out what's wrong in my code.
As i call the function `clean()` it cleans the screen without ever showing a `<div>`.
If i call the function `togglevisible()` it shows the div i clicked on, although on a new element click it doesn't hide the first element, unhiding the second element below the first element.
How can i hide an element after clicking on a new one in Javascript?
This is the code i'm using atm:

```js
function clean() {
  if (previous_value !== null) {
    var hide = document.getElementById(previous_value);
    hide.style.display = "none";
  }
  togglevisible();
}

function togglevisible() {
  var dropdown = document.getElementById("dropdownCenterBtn");
  var current_value = dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].value;
  var previous_value = current_value;
  
  if (current_value !== null) {
    var selected = document.getElementById(current_value);
    selected.style.display = "flex";
  } else {
    var selected = document.getElementById(current_value);
    selected.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown-center">
  <select class="dropdown-menu" id="dropdownCenterBtn" onchange="clean()">
    <option>Courses List</option>
    <option>------------</option>
    <option value="div1">Introduction to Computer Science</option>
    <option value="div2">Web Programming with Python and Javascript</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="div1" id="div1">
  <h3>Introduction</h3>
</div>

<div class="div2" id="div2">
  <h3>Web Programming</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you see the error in the browser console? That's a big clue. Be sure you understand how to debug your code using console logs and breakpoints.

Comment: You're using a variable `previous_value ` defined in another function... Please fix `previous_value ` scope.

Comment: It doesn't look like there is a reason for two separate functions. You could easily fix the issue with the improperly scoped previous_value variable by combining into one function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You went way too far. Here's a quick solution for that.

```js
function clean(event) 
{
  var divs = document.querySelectorAll(".div");
  
  divs.forEach(function (div){
    if(div.id === event.target.value && div.style.display == "none")
        div.style.display = "flex";
    else if(div.style.display !== "none")
        div.style.display = "none";
  });
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown-center">
  <select class="dropdown-menu" id="dropdownCenterBtn" onchange="clean(event)">
    <option>Courses List</option>
    <option>------------</option>
    <option value="div1">Introduction to Computer Science</option>
    <option value="div2">Web Programming with Python and Javascript</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="div1 div" id="div1">
  <h3>Introduction</h3>
</div>

<div class="div2 div" id="div2">
  <h3>Web Programming</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: It works! Could you quickly explain why there is "div" after "div1" and "div2" in their classes?
I'll study the javascript function for future implementations.
Thanks

Comment: Got it. It's for QuerySelectorAll.
Thanks for your help

Comment: Shot @var-log. I was busy, Sorry I couldn't attend to your comment earlier.